# Will replacing intel CPU in laptop fix failing HD 4600 graphics?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard

I have a Toshiba Satellite P75 with a socketed i7 4700MQ CPU that my daughter has been using.  She used it without good ventilation and now the screen has permanent artifacts that persist between boots and while the BIOS is loading.  I was looking for an inexpensive solution and came across some used CPU's on ebay.  Before I buy one, I'd like to be reasonably sure that replacing the CPU will fix the graphics issue.  The Satellite uses only the Intel onboard graphics but I am unsure if there is some other hardware on the motherboard that could be at fault.

Comment: Could it be the screen itself? What sort of artifacts are you seeing?

Comment: Considering Intel Graphics are nearly always integrated into the GPU for the past decade or so now, the short answer is that replacing the CPU will replace the GPU. The issue is whether we actually *know* that the GPU is the problem.

Comment: After testing with the built in SVGA and HDMI connectors the artifacts don't appear on the other monitors.  I am guessing that means the problem is likely the screen (a cheaper fix than the CPU).